# Extract content from my string with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to extract the content from my string, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
Joe tracksuit for only 3,50€ 66% Discount!
```

I only need to get the number 66 off the price discount.  I'm doing it this way, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
<?php


$str = 'Joe tracksuit for only 3,50€ 66% Discount!';
$double = preg_replace('/[a-z]/i','',$double); 
$double = str_replace('%','',$double);  


echo $double ; //RESULT-> 3.50€ 66

?>
```

Comment: Well, your code is only stripping letters and the percent sign..

Comment: Might be better to approach it from a different direction and do a preg_match for `/([\d]+)%/i`

Comment: @Richard: For reference, you don't need `[\d]`. `\d` will do.